# Is my Git workflow correct?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I am using TortoiseGit for my Git workflow and I am wondering if perhaps I might be missing some commands that might simplify things. Here is my current flow.

1. Create and switch to new branch off of `master` branch. Name the new branch `NewStuff`
2. Make changes inside `NewStuff` branch and then commit
3. Push `NewStuff` branch to repo (say Bitbucket)
4. Switch to local `master` branch and pull latest `master` changes from repo into it
5. Switch to `NewStuff` branch and pull local master branch into it
6. If no conflicts, then switch to `master` branch and pull the `NewStuff` branch into it.
7. Push `master` branch up to server repo

Is this the correct flow to be using Git or is there a better way? I see commands such as `Merge` that I am not making use of so I am wondering if there is a better method.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you could simplify your workflow

1. Create and switch to new branch off of master branch. Name the new branch NewStuff
2. Make changes inside NewStuff branch and then commit
3. Rebase NewStuff branch on top of origin/master `git rebase origin/master`
4. Push NewStuff to remote (BitBucket or GitHub for example)
5. Make Pull Request to merge origin/NewStuff onto origin/master

Answer (score 0):

> Push NewStuff branch to repo (say Bitbucket)

Why? So others can see it? Or as some kind of backup?

> Switch to NewStuff branch and pull local master branch into it

Make that a rebase instead of pull (a.k.a. merge) and you have a winner.